# People Dancing Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am having trouble with an algorithmic problem that goes like this:

N people line up in some order (Each of their positions are marked as 1...N.), and then perform successive dance moves, which reorders their positions.

A set of dance moves is described with N numbers, call them d1, d2, d3, ... dn. The person in position i corresponds to dance move di. During the dance move, each person moves to his or her new location. Not all values of di are distinct, which means that some people may be placed on the same square. This means that they will move together for the rest of the remaining dances.

**Input:**

The first line inputs N (the number of people), and the next line inputs d1, d2, d3 ... dn.

**Output**

I must output the number of positions that will ALWAYS contain people, no matter how many shuffles take place.

**Example Input:**

4

3 2 1 3

**Analysis:**

Here, N = 4 and d1 = 3, d2 = 2, d3 = 1, d4 = 3

The output here will be **3** because there will always be people in spaces 1, 2, and 3.

In the first shuffle, person 1 and 4 will be "mapped" to index 3. Person 2 will be "mapped" to index 1, and person 3 will be "mapped" to index 2. No matter how many times this dance process continues, these three spots will always be occupied, because the numbers 3, 1, 2 are in the first three numbers, and these are the three spots that are occupied.

-

I am not sure if this requires some sort of special data structure or something? Perhaps a queue? I have tried some of my ideas for a couple of hours, but I cannot come up with anything. Any help is much appreciated.

I created an array of integers [1...N] representing the original positions of the people, and I made another array [d1 ... dn] representing the mapping corresponding to each index. Through some research, I found "multisets," which may be relevant. I tried messing around with those, as well as ArrayList, but I still couldn't make much progress.

Comment: Will you need to input a series of dance steps?  That is, will there ever be multiple lines giving d1 through dN?

Comment: No, it will always be one line. The set of dance moves repeats supposedly infinitely many times.

Comment: *The output here will be 3 because there will always be people in spaces 1, 2, and 3.* No, because with your current example, the result is 3 after the first time the sequence is executed, but becomes 2 after the second time the sequence is executed. After that, it stays constant at 2.

Comment: Say the order of the people (before any execution) is just {1, 2, 3, 4}. Then, after one execution (according to the mapping above), I think it should become {2, 3, {1, 4}, [empty]}. Subsequently (following the same mapping), it becomes {3, {1, 4}, 2, [empty]}, and so on. This is my understanding of the problem; however, the input/output above is provided. Spots 1-3 are always occupied

Comment: Well, first of all the numbers in your example input and your subsequent analysis don't line up. But if I go with your example input, let's say that initially, there's one person on every position: `[1, 1, 1, 1]`. After iteration one, this becomes: `[1, 2, 1, 0]`. After iteration two, this becomes: `[2, 2, 0, 0]`. Subsequent iterations no longer change this result.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just realized this, and I have edited the question. You are correct that for the example input, the answer should have been 2 (now updated to match analysis).

Comment: Same scenario for the new example input: `[1, 1, 1, 1]` -> `[2, 1, 1, 0]` -> `[3, 1, 0, 0]`, then stabilizes.

Comment: Do the numbers represent the number of people on the corresponding index here? If so, it should be [1, 1, 1, 1] --> [1, 1, 2, 0] --> [2, 1, 1, 0] -> [1, 1, 2, 0].

Comment: Are you talking about the result after every move? Or after every full sequence of moves?

Comment: The full sequence of moves. (the last index in the example no longer be mapped after the first iteration since nobody is occupying that spot.)

Comment: Then I don't see how you get to those results. If we look at the execution of the steps in only the first sequence, I have: `[1, 1, 1, 1]` -> `[0, 1, 2, 1]` -> `[0, 1, 2, 1]` -> `[2, 1, 0, 1]` -> `[2, 1, 1, 0]`. So I don't see how you get to `[1, 1, 2, 0]` after the first iteration.

Comment: I am getting [1, 1, 1, 1] -> [1, 1, 2, 0]. Each person is mapped to the corresponding index in [3, 2, 1, 3], which means that the first index in [1, 1, 1, 1] goes to index 3. The second one goes to index 2, and the third one goes to index 1. The last one also goes to index 3. Since there is no "4" in the dancing moves array, nothing is mapped to the last index in the array, which means that it is at zero.

Comment: Think you missed a part in your assignment: *"This means that they will move together for the rest of the remaining dances."*

Comment: Hmm, the example input/output I have currently in OP is provided to me (with output of 3). I believe that after arriving at [1, 1, 2, 0], it follows [3, 2, 1, 3] again. The first index, 1, is mapped to the 3rd index. The second index, also 1, is mapped to the second index. The third index, 2, is mapped to the first index. Since there is nobody at the last spot, it cannot be mapped, which gives [2, 1, 1, 0]. No matter how many times the people follow this set of dance moves, the first three places remain occupied. I think that all of the mappings be thought of as instantaneously occuring.

Comment: Hmmmm, that changes things. Wouldn't the solution then just always be `Arrays.stream(moves).distinct().count()`?

Comment: A counterexample: N = 4, dancing moves = {1, 1, 2, 3}. Here, the we would have the sequence [1, 1, 1, 1] -> [2, 1, 1, 0] -> [3, 1, 0, 0] -> [4, 0, 0, 0], so the output would be "1," whereas the line of code outputs "3"

Comment: I think that your idea of "snapshotting" might work. What if every snapshot were stored into an array or something, and once we get a snapshot that we have already arrived at, we can conclude that it has stabilized (it will begin to cycle then). Then we can count the number of non-zero elements, and that should be the answer?

Comment: Just saw your edited post. Thank you so much. You have been extremely helpful to me.

Comment: It's too bad that the question got downvoted so much. I have a feeling that there is possibly a more mathematical approach to this problem, and I would have liked to see someone post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Current answer**

The previous answer assumed that the movement of people to their new positions would be sequential, i.e. people would start moving together within the same sequence.

The answer below assumes that the movement within the same sequence is instantaneous. It uses two arrays to map people from their old positions to their new positions, and continues running the sequence as long as there is a reduction in the total number of spaces occupied.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfPeople = 4;
    int[] moves = new int[]{3, 2, 1, 3};
    int[] positions = new int[numberOfPeople];

    Arrays.fill(positions, 1);

    int positionsOccupied;

    do {
        positionsOccupied = positionsOccupied(positions);
        positions = dance(positions, moves);

    } while (positionsOccupied(positions) < positionsOccupied);

    System.out.println("Result: " + positionsOccupied(positions));
}

public static int[] dance(int[] oldPositions, int[] moves) {
    int[] newPositions = new int[oldPositions.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < oldPositions.length; i++) {
        newPositions[moves[i] - 1] += oldPositions[i];
    }

    return newPositions;
}

public static int positionsOccupied(int[] positions) {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (positions[i] > 0) {
            result++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Previous answer**

You actually only need one array to hold the `positions`, and an additional array to hold a `snapshot` of the previous state.

After every iteration, the snapshot is compared with the current positions, and if they're equal this means that subsequent invocations of the dance sequence will have no further impact on the positions and that you can calculate a final result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfPeople = 4;
    int[] moves = new int[]{3, 2, 1, 3};
    int[] positions = new int[numberOfPeople];

    Arrays.fill(positions, 1);

    int[] snapshot;

    do {
        snapshot = Arrays.copyOf(positions, positions.length);

        dance(positions, moves);
    } while (!Arrays.equals(positions, snapshot));

    System.out.println("Result: " + positionsOccupied(positions));
}

public static void dance(int[] positions, int[] moves) {
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        int currentNumber = positions[i];
        positions[i] = 0;
        positions[moves[i] - 1] += currentNumber;
    }
}

public static int positionsOccupied(int[] positions) {
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (positions[i] > 0) {
            result++;
        }
    }


    return result;
}
```